# iOS account about to expire, download beta iOS8?

Tags: ios

My iOS account is going to expire in a couple days--if I download the beta iOS8 on my phone, will I be stuck in an early beta with no way of updating to later versions of the beta?

Comment: This isnt a coding problem...

Comment: @craig1231 But it is related to common development tools. So this question is still marginally on topic.

Comment: @rmaddy Would this still be off topic as an "ask support" kind of question? I'd be surprised if Apple didn't have a process for this kind of thing.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I don't follow. I said this question is on topic, not off topic.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm asking if it's off topic because of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) reason.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Possibly. Vote to close if you feel it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to renew your account, don't download beta software. While an iOS device has beta software, it also has a certificate which authenticates it to use the beta software and will eventually expire, preventing you from using the device at all (it'll be bricked).

I had this happen to me once. The only option was to downgrade the device to a non-beta version. That was an extremely painful and difficult process requiring me to use software that had been created for jailbreaking iOS devices - if no such software is available for iOS 8 yet, then you'd probably just be plain screwed (I don't know the current status of software for jailbreaking iOS 7/8).